# Plot a line graph linked to a secondary y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I a trying to replicate what can be easily done in an excel. 
Using ggplot, I tried to plot the following:

1. Plot a barchart, where the left Y axis is represented  in counts (0-600)
2. plot a line graph where the right Y axis is represented in % (0-100).

qn1 . Can someone explain to me, how can I link my percentage data to my secondary axis? Currently the line graph (which should represent the %) is plotted based on the primary Y axis using the counts scale.

qn2. How can i change the 2 scales independently?

qn3. How can i name the 2 scales independently?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=data,aes(x=sch,y=count,fill=category),stat = "identity")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkcyan", "indianred1")) +
  geom_line(data=data_percentage, aes(x=sch, y=count, group=1)) + 
  geom_point(data=data_percentage, aes(x=sch, y=count, group=1)) +
  geom_text(data=data_percentage,aes(x=scht,label=paste(count,"%",sep="")),size=3) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./2), name="%")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"), 
        plot.title = element_text(size=11, face="bold", hjust=0.3), 
        legend.position = "top", legend.text = element_text(size=9)) +
  labs(fill="") + guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))+
  ylab("No. Recruited") + ggtitle("2. No. of students")
```

Comment: @PalvinderKaur There exist *a lot* of questions and excellent answers around each of your 3 questions here on SO. Please spend some time researching before posting here. It also good advice to stick to the one-question-per-post rule.

Comment: @Tino Thank you Tino. I will look at this example and try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Answer1: You don't link the `geom` to an axis. Instead, you scale it up or down to be consistent with your secondary axis scale. In the example you provided, `sec.axis` is scaled by `~./2` then your `y` aesthetic in both `geom_line` and `geom_point` should be `count*2`. This will give and appearance that the line is linked to the secondary axis.

Answer2: You can't. In ggplot, the secondary axis should be a one-to-one transformation of the primary axis. I don't know if another package could do that.

Answer3: just move the `name` argument within the function `scale_y_continuous` to inside the function `sec_axis` as the example code shown below.

The code will look something like this:

```
ggplot() +
  .
  .
  geom_line(data = data_percentage, aes(x=sch, y=count*2, group=1)) +
  geom_point(data = data_percentage, aes(x=sch, y=count*2, group=1)) + 
  .
  .
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./2, name="%"))+
  .
  . 
  .
```

Comment: Here's the author of ggplot's reasoning for purposely avoiding secondary axes, eventually added in v2.2.0:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876

Comment: Thank you very much for replying to my 3 questions @Abdallah Atef.

Comment: @Pavinder Glad that it helped. You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)